# Writing tests for Python Eve RESTful APIs against a real MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, testing, eve

I am developing my API server with Python-eve, and would like to know how to test the API endpoints. A few things that I would like to test specifically:

- Validation of POST/PATCH requests
- Authentication of different endpoints
- Before_ and after_ hooks working property
- Returning correct JSON response

Currently I am testing the app against a real MongoDB, and I can imagine the testing will take a long time to run once I have hundreds or thousands of tests to run. Mocking up stuff is another approach but I couldn't find tools that allow me to do that while keeping the tests as realistic as possible. I am wondering if there is a recommended way to test eve apps. Thanks!

Here is what I am having now:

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
from myModule import create_app
import unittest, json

class ClientAppsTests(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    app = create_app()
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    self.app = app.test_client()

    # Insert some fake data
    client = MongoClient(app.config['MONGO_HOST'], app.config['MONGO_PORT'])
    self.db = client[app.config['MONGO_DBNAME']]
    new_app = {
      'client_id'     : 'test',
      'client_secret' : 'secret',
      'token'         : 'token'
    }
    self.db.client_apps.insert(new_app)

  def tearDown(self):
    self.db.client_apps.remove()

  def test_access_public_token(self):
    res = self.app.get('/token')
    assert res.status_code == 200

  def test_get_token(self):
    query = { 'client_id': 'test', 'client_secret': 'secret' }
    res = self.app.get('/token', query_string=query)
    res_obj = json.loads(res.get_data())
    assert res_obj['token'] == 'token'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Eve test suite itself is [using a test db](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/blob/develop/eve/tests/__init__.py#L62-L88) and not mocking anything. The test db gets created and dropped on every run to guarantee isolation (not super fast yes, but as close as possible to a production environment). While of course you should test your own code, you probably don't need to write tests like `test_access_public_token` above since, stuff like that is covered by the Eve suite already. You might want to check the [Eve Mocker](https://github.com/tsileo/eve-mocker) extension too.

Also make yourself familiar with [Authentication and Authorization tutorials](http://python-eve.org/authentication.html). It looks like the way you're going get the whole token thing going is not really appropriate (you want to use request headers for that kind of stuff).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will keep using a test db as Eve does for now and it's good because everything is real, unless it gets too slow. And I guess Eve Mocker doesn't really suit our needs.

As far as testing `test_access_public_token`, the purpose is double checking authorization (in case we make certain private endpoints public by accident) I know it's kind of redundant but good to have it.

Regarding the token thing, the endpoint is for getting a app-wide token the first time with client_app_id and secret, and will use that in the following req in the header with token-based auth you mentioned.

Comment: By the way, is it possible to use custom header instead of the standard `Authorization` header for the authentication? Thanks!