# Unit Test cases for Python Eve Webservices

Tags: python, web-services, unit-testing, eve

We have developed the APIs using the `python eve` framework . Is there a way we can write the unit test cases for the APIs we have developed in `EVE`. Is there a Unit Test case component bundled into `Python EVE`.I need to bundle them with my Continuous Integration setup.
If yes please help me with the steps how to proceed with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing tests for Python Eve RESTful APIs against a real MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23748571/writing-tests-for-python-eve-restful-apis-against-a-real-mongodb)

Comment: I had a look on the wiki link . I think I have a bit of different problem to solve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start by looking at Eve's own [test suite](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/tree/develop/eve/tests). There's 600+ examples in there. There are two base classes that provide a lot of utility methods: `TestMinimal` and `TestBase`. Almost all other test classes inherit from either of those. You probably want to use `TestMinimal` as it takes care of setting up and dropping the MongoDB connection for you. It also provides stuff like `assert200`, `assert404` etc.

In general, you use the `test_client` object, as you do with Flask itself. Have a look at [Testing Flask Applications](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/) too and Eve's [Running the Tests](http://python-eve.org/testing.html) page.

Comment: Thanks Nicola, for the answer I will look into the test suite

Comment: What about a more live situation in which i want to test i using actual requests? Is there something out of the box for that?

Comment: the test suites link throws 404?? Please check the answer.